# Python & QuickBooks Database

Tags: python, quickbooks, iif

I'd like to use Python to pull all product information from a *Intuit QuickBooks Enterprise Solutions - Manufacturing and Wholesale Edition 12.0* database.

The QB install I refer to is on an Intranet server and I only need to access it internally (same network ID).

I just need someone to point me in the right direction, or give an example of pulling product info from a QB database via Python. I've searched and read for hours regarding people attempting to use Python with QuickBooks, but there's a lot of QB terminology that's all Greek to me, e.g., should I be using IDS? What about QB XML? The COM interface method looks dreadful.

The simplest option, I suppose, would be to export the QB product database/list as IIF, then sifting through/utilizing that export. This is not something that will have to be done often, so ease-of-use/simplicity takes precedence over speed.

If anyone has any keen methods for reading/writing data from a QB database, please let me know!

Comment: are you still active?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, there is *no* easy answer.

Intuit is moving everything - including data - to their cloud system.

The 'correct' answer use [the SDK](https://developer.intuit.com/us#QuickBooksDesktopSDK).
The SDK is the 'official' way for doing everything. but it does not support Python natively.

The middle ground solution: [use the SDK + Web Connector with Python](http://marketplace.intuit.com/webconnector/).

Now, back at your questions: [one very GOOD pointer](http://blog.bflarsen.com/?p=132)

But please be aware that the SDK will be less and less supported as Intuit moves to the cloud and locks in the subscription model.

Comment: So what if the Quickbooks is running local.  Would you be able to extract/update records via the SDK?

Comment: Is there any way to create values in QB from python?